# zsh prompt does not seem to work even when setting prompt_subst

Tags: zsh, zshrc

I'm having some issues with my prompt (https://gist.github.com/zackp30/ccf91d6e476f1b6b8ec4), it only displays "anothertest", but it should toggle on every command, and, if this helps, $PS1 is set to "anothertest", and not the _zprompt_init function, any help will be greatly appreciated, I have also made sure prompt_subst is set.
Thanks, Zack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the comparison in line 10:

```
if [[ a == 1 ]] ; then
```

it has to be:

```
if [[ $a == 1 ]] ; then
```

In order to recall the value of parameters you have to prepend `$` to their name.

Comment: Thanks! I'm very new to shell script, still used to not prepending $ to variables, thanks again!